# Replace the image of imageview onclick when pressed before redirecting

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview

I have several Images Inside linear layout. I want to change there Image source upon click before redirecting to next activity. My linear layout is finally enclosed in fragment. That fragment I have used in main activity. What should I do to change the source?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="setContentView"
            android:id="@+id/campus"
            android:contextClickable="false">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/acad"
                android:src="@drawable/nap"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ACADEMIA"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textColor="#993300"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: The image shows the layout I am trying to change, an image with brown b/g is changing to white]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX7VN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the drawable  **selector.xml**

Take nap_click drawable what you want after click and nap in normal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nap_click" android:state_pressed= "true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nap"/>

</selector>
```

And set to Your src or background in xml

```
  android:src="@drawable/selector"
```

or

```
  android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

You want Like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="3"
  >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus"

        android:weightSum="1"

        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad2"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad1"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus3"

        android:weightSum="1"

        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad3"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad5"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad4"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus6"

        android:weightSum="1"

        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad6"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad7"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad8"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus9"

        android:weightSum="1"

        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad9"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad10"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/campus11"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/acad11"
            android:src="@drawable/apply_job"

            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"  />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACADEMIA"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:textColor="#993300"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="#993400" android:state_pressed= "true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#FFFFFF"/>

</selector>
```

apply_job.png are here .png or otherwise you take the other pressed or normal

You setonclicklistner On layout like

```
campus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Change the textColor on click 


       // txtHelp.setTextColor();

        }
    });
```

Or used the TouchonListner....

Comment: Thanks alot, this is what I was exactly looking for. It worked. 
Can you help further, how this can be done for 3x4 size layout.

like I have 4 rows containing three images in different linear layout. I want to implement this on 12 items.

Comment: Sure, I'd done, this was my first question here. Can you help further for 11 other ImageView.
How I can make changes for them?

Comment: Do this for all....... also if you use only one than take this only  drawable as color/your color on state pressed and at normal take transparent... and set to src and at backgroud set your image

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/fav" android:state_pressed= "true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/acad"/>
</selector>

And this is another drawable resource file, 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item  android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>

how to combine both and add changes for all images

Comment: Wait I Update the answer

Comment: ok! I will also update snapshot of one horizontal row for understanding